# Plot.ly: Simple prefix or suffix for hover text

Tags: d3.js, plotly

I've tried reading the documentation but I haven't found a simple way to add a suffix to a hover text.
Is there a way to add text to the `hoverformat`? For example `y respondents` where y is the y value.

The setting `yaxis: {hoverformat: ''}` does not seem to allow strings?
I'm used to working with FlotChart where you can simply put `"%y respondents"`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set [`text`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#scatter-text) in your trace you can get a suffix.

> Sets text elements associated with each (x,y) pair. If a single
>   string, the same string appears over all the data points. If an array
>   of string, the items are mapped in order to the this trace's (x,y)
>   coordinates.

Together with [`hoverinfo`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#scatter-hoverinfo) (`hoverinfo: 'text+y'`) you get close to what you what you want (except for the unneeded line break which would need to be removed manually).

---

For bar charts this does not seem to work (at least not in Jan 2017). It is necessary to replicate the data and write it into an array in the text attribute (which also solves the line break issue).

```js
var N = 16,
  x = Plotly.d3.range(N).map(Plotly.d3.random.normal(3, 1)),
  y = Plotly.d3.range(N),

  data = [{
    x: x,
    y: y,
    type: 'scatter',
    mode: 'markers',
    text: 'respondents',
    marker: {
      size: 16
    },
    hoverinfo: 'text+y'
  }],
  layout = {
    hovermode: 'closest',
  };

Plotly.plot('myDiv', data, layout);

//here comes the bar chart
var data = [{
  x: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'],
  y: [20, 14, 25],
  type: 'bar',
  text: [],
  hoverinfo: 'text'
}];

for (N = 0; N < data[0].y.length; N += 1) {
  data[0].text.push(data[0].y[N] + ' Respondents');
}
Plotly.plot('myBarChart', data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></div>
<div id="myBarChart" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The solution works for a scatter plot. Strangely it doesn't work for a bar chart. I've accepted your answer as this requirement was not part of my question.